# Run bitnami/kafka with TLS

Tags: linux, docker, apache-kafka

I'm trying to run bitnami/kafka in docker with TLS, and get the error, that keystore.jks and truststore.jks does not mounted correct.

```bash
docker run --name kafka_ssl \
  -p 9092:9092 \
  -p 9093:9093 \
  -v ${HOME}/.localdev/ssl/tmp/keystore/localdev_keystore.jks:/bitnami/kafka/conf/certs/kafka.keystore.jks \
  -v ${HOME}/.localdev/ssl/tmp/truststore/localdev_truststore.jks:/bitnami/kafka/conf/certs/kafka.truststore.jks \
  -e ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes \
  -e KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=${DOCKER_VM_HOST}:2181 \
  -e KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL \
  -e KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092,SSL://localhost:9093 \
  -e KAFKA_CFG_SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION=/bitnami/kafka/conf/certs/kafka.keystore.jks \
  -e KAFKA_CFG_SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD=password \
  -e KAFKA_CFG_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION=/bitnami/kafka/conf/certs/kafka.truststore.jks \
  -e KAFKA_CFG_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD=password \
  -e KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:9092,SSL://:9093 \
  -e KAFKA_CFG_SSL_ENDPOINT_IDENTIFICATION_ALGORITHM= \
  ${DOCKER_BASE_REGISTRY}/bitnami/kafka:2.8.1
```

Expected: success ran container
Actual:

```
kafka 11:01:30.08 ERROR ==> In order to configure the TLS encryption for Kafka with JKS certs you must mount your kafka.keystore.jks and kafka.truststore.jks certs to the /bitnami/kafka/config/certs directory.
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to create first a localdev_keystore.jks and localdev_truststore.jks see in your docker run the command you are creating a volume pointing to that required jks files.
You can use the next guide to create those certificates using openssl.
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19509-01/820-3503/6nf1il6er/index.html